# operator== with double dispatch in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, double-dispatch

How should one implement

```
operator==(const Base& base)
```

to compare subclasses s.t. the calls would be properly dispatched when called as

```
Base* base1 = new Derived1();
Base* base2 = new Derived2();
base1->operator==(*base2)?
```

Comment: `operator==` should be implemented as a free-standing functions, otherwise it is not symmetrical in its arguments.

Comment: There is a good discussion of double dispatch in More Effective C++.

Comment: It is possible for a `Derived1` to be equal to a `Derived2`?
Please give more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Implement operator== as a free standing function.
2. Have it call a virtual method on one of the arguments (e.g. IsEqual())

That gets you to the point where you have

```
Derived1::IsEqual(const Base& base)
```

Called.  From here you have some options

1. Use RTTI to dynamic_cast<> base to Derived1
2. If the number of derived is small and finite, you can implement

   ```
   virtual bool Base::IsEqualToDerived(const Derived1& d) {return false};
   virtual bool Base::IsEqualToDerived(const Derived2& d) {return false};
   ```

as virtual methods.  In Derived1, you override and compare for real.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a generic C++ question on classes and type rather than a specific question on the operator== . Up to my knowledge, in the particular example you are giving there is no other way but to use [dynamic_cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast)

Comment: You can (and probably should) do it without dynamic_cast using virtual functions.

Comment: Well it depends is the issue about base1 receiving the proper call or being able to tell that the input argument is Derived2 instead of just Base ?

The first will be solved using virtual function (I agree), the second, using dynamic_cast